# Parallelism in the sentence

Tags: parallelism

> The only way to know is ***taking/ to take*** the plunge.

Are both ***taking*** and ***to take*** correct in this sentence? If not then explain why?

Comment: What do you think it is?

Comment: Correct :The only way to know is to take the plunge.

Comment: Then what is your real question?

Comment: Why "to take" is correct but, "taking" is wrong ?

Comment: Then edit your question. Click on "edit" and replace _What is the mistake in this sentence?_ with the question you just stated. however, I would also suggest you tell us what research you have done to try and find the answer yourself. Otherwise, as you can see, your question will be probably closed.

Comment: I just want to the reason why both are not correct because both are correct to me.

Comment: Would you explain my question's answer? As i have confusion that's why i asked your site.

Comment: I am sure somebody will. Be patient.

Comment: Thanks for your positive reply

Answer (score 1):

Correct: The only way to know is **to take** the plunge.

"To take" is correct because the plunging will occur in the future.

See [Know the Difference: Gerunds vs Infinitives](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerunds-infinitives/)

> ### Gerunds
>
> Gerunds are best for use in sentences about actions that are real or
> complete, or that have been completed.
>
> • I stopped worrying about the future.
>
> In this example, the worrying was real and it happened until I
> stopped.
>
> • We really enjoy climbing mountains.
>
> In this example, the climbing is real and it’s something we like to
> do.
>
> ### Infinitives
>
> Infinitives are best for use in sentences about actions that are
> unreal or abstract, or that will occur in the future.
>
> • I’d like you to think about something.
>
> In this example, I’m asking you to think about something, but the
> thinking hasn’t happened yet.
>
> • Can we take a walk without you stopping to smoke?
>
> In this example, we’re talking about taking a walk and the smoking
> hasn’t happened yet.